# Efficient cronjob recommendation

Tags: php, algorithm, mongodb, cron

Brief overview about my usecase: Consider a database (most probably mongodb) having a million entries. The value for each entry needs to be updated everyday by calling an API. How to design such a cronjob? I know Facebook does something similar. The only thing I can think of is to have multiple jobs which divide the database entries into batches and each job updates a batch. I am certain there are smarter solutions out there. I am also not sure what technology to use. Any advise is appreciated.

-Karan

Comment: I very much doubt Facebook does routinely update millions of records as a cronjob task. What would those daily updates to _all_ of your records involve?

Comment: Oh is that the case. My bad then. I thought FB did that. The reason I wanted to do something like this was to keep the caches warm and updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the updated question context of "keeping the caches warm", a strategy of touching all of your database documents would likely diminish rather than improve performance unless that data will comfortably fit into available memory.

[Caching](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching) in MongoDB relies on the operating system behaviour for file system cache, which typically frees cache by following a Least Recently Used (LRU) approach.  This means that over time, the working data set in memory should naturally be the "warm" data.

If you force data to be read into memory, you could be loading documents that are rarely (or never) accessed by end users .. potentially at the expense of data that may actually be requested more frequently by the application users.

There is a use case for "prewarming" the cache .. for example when you restart a MongoDB server and want to load data or indexes into memory.

In MongoDB 2.2, you can use the new [`touch` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/) for this purpose.

Other strategies for prewarming are essentially doing reverse optimization with an [`explain()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain).  Instead of trying to minimize the number of index entries (`nscanned`) and documents (`nscannedObjects`), you would write a query that intentionally will maximize these entries.

With your API response time goal .. even if someone's initial call required their data to be fetched into memory, that should still be a reasonably quick indexed retrieval.  A goal of 3 to 4 seconds response seems generous unless your application has a lot of processing overhead: the default "slow" query value in MongoDB is 100ms.

Answer (score 0):

From a technical standpoint, You can execute scripts in the mongodb shell, and execute them via cron.  If you schedule cron to run a command like:

`./mongo server:27017/dbname--quiet my_commands.js`

Mongodb will execute the contents of the my_commands.js script.  Now, for an overly simple example just to illustrate the concept.  If you wanted to find a person named `sara` and insert an attribute  (yes, unrealistic example) you could enter the following in your `.js` script file.

```
person = db.person.findOne( { name : "sara" } );
person.validated = "true";
db.people.save( person );
```

Then everytime the cron runs, that record will be updated.  Now, add a loop and a call to your api, and you might have a solution.  More information on these commands and example can be found in the [mongodb docs](http://downloads.mongodb.org/docs/mongodb-docs-2011-09-15.pdf).

However, from a design perspective, are you sure you need to update every single record each night?  Is there a way to identify a more reasonable subset of records that need to be processed?  Or possibly can the api be called on the data as it's retrieved and served to whomever is going to consume it?

Comment: Updating each and every record might be inefficient yes. My goal is to keep the caches warm and updated. The API can be called in realtime as well but the SLA for the API is high (around 3-4 seconds).